# Get value by filtering a list

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a list property in a DTO and this list has the following values returned from a property:

```cs
var myDTO = new MyDTO
{
    DocumentMetaData = new List<Item>
    { 
        new Item { PropertyName = "Prop1", Value = "John" },
        new Item { PropertyName = "Prop2", Value = "Mary" },
        new Item { PropertyName = "Prop3", Value = "Paul" }
    }
}
```

This DTO has other properties, but they are not relevant in this question.

So, I'm looking for a way to get the value "Mary" from the property "Prop2". I tried to do the following in Logic App, but it's not best approach:

```
body('API_-_GET_-_Document')?['DocumentMetaData']?[1]?['Value']
```

Is there a way to filter by property "Prop2" in Logic App?

Comment: I have no clue what language that syntax is, but it's certainly not C# (the second piece of code, not the  first). Please [edit] your question and add the appropriate language tag. Also, "it's not the best approach" according to whom and why?

Comment: For the 2nd piece of code, ok to not know what it is, so I edited the post... but, for the 1st code, it's very clear it's a C# code

Comment: I imagine that if `PropertyName` is always unique as in your example, you could use a `Dictionary<string, Item>` instead, and then do `body('API_-_GET_-_Document')?['DocumentMetaData']?['Prop2']?['Value']`. Is that perhaps what you're after?

Comment: The values of PropertyName is always the same, unique like you said. So it's always "Prop1", "Prop2" and "Prop3"... I specifically need the value of the property Value for the PropertyName "Prop2"... 

The solution you proposed is considering that "Prop2" is a property in Item, which is not.

Comment: So you can return a Dictionary instead of a list, which should work

Comment: Camilo, I can't change to a Dictionary unfortunately, it must be a list for now... The C# side is done, I'm looking to the LogicApp side now :-)

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with the LogicApp-syntax I cannot help very much, but probably the [contains-function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#contains) can be used to filter the array for `Prop2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Filter Array action to achieve that:

[image]

```
"Filter_array": {
    "inputs": {
        "from": "body('API_-_GET_-_Document')?['DocumentMetaData']",
        "where": "@equals(item()['PropertyName'], 'Prop2')"
    },
    ...
    "type": "Query"
}
```

Then in your sample, you should only have one element, so you can take the first element of your array:

```
first(body('Filter_array'))['Value']
```